# HTML Dropdown filter based on another dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I tried dropdown filter based on another dropdown,
It's working If I don't use space in the **value** in option.
If I use space in **value**, then it's not working.

```js
$("#Type").on("change", function() {
  var values = $(this).val().split(',', ) //split value which is selected
  $("#fruits option").hide() //hide all options from slect box
  //loop through values
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var vals = values[i]
    $("#fruits option[value=" + vals + "]").show() //show that option

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row last">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="">Department</label>
    <select id="Type" name="Type" class='form-control'>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value='Apple'>Diet 1</option>
      <option value='Red Banana,Green Apple'>Diet 2</option>
    </select>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="">Device</label>
    <select id="fruits" name="fruits" class='form-control'>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value='Apple'>Apple</option>
      <option value='Red Banana'>Banana</option>
      <option value='Green Apple'>G Apple</option>
    </select>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here If I select **Apple** value - **Diet 1**, it's working.
If I select **Diet 2**, it should show **Banana and G Apple** in second drop down.
Please help me how to get the **Red Banana** value from 1st dropdown and filter the second dropdown,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't far off you just missing closing single quotation marts in this line:

before:

```
 $("#fruits option[value=" + vals + "]").show() /
```

after

```
 $("#fruits option[value='" + vals + "']").show() /
```

```js
$("#Type").on("change", function() {
debugger
  var values = $(this).val().split(',', ) //split value which is selected
  $("#fruits option").hide() //hide all options from slect box
  //loop through values
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var vals = values[i]
    $("#fruits option[value='" + vals + "']").show() //show that option

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row last">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="">Department</label>
    <select id="Type" name="Type" class='form-control'>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value='Apple'>Diet 1</option>
      <option value='Red Banana,Green Apple'>Diet 2</option>
    </select>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="">Device</label>
    <select id="fruits" name="fruits" class='form-control'>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value='Apple'>Apple</option>
      <option value='Red Banana'>Banana</option>
      <option value='Green Apple'>G Apple</option>
    </select>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: np problem happy to help

Comment: I have a list [{'value': 'Apple',
  'product': 'Green Apple'},{'value': 'Grape',
  'product': 'Fresh Grape'}] I want to use this list in fruits id (2nd dropdown) instead manual values. Can you support

I used this for loop but no luck
{% for data in product_name %}
  <option value={{data.value}}>{{data.product}}</option>    
{% endfor %}

Comment: yes its possible please see the new answer for an example

Answer (score 0):

Biased on you follow up question here is an example of the second drop down bound to an array instead of being hard coded

```js
var data = [{
  'value': 'Apple',
  'product': 'Green Apple'
}, {
  'value': 'Grape',
  'product': 'Fresh Grape'
}];

$(function() {
  $.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
    $('#fruits').append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("value", itemData.product)
      .text(itemData.value));
  });
})

$("#Type").on("change", function() {

  var values = $(this).val().split(',', ) //split value which is selected
  $("#fruits option").hide() //hide all options from slect box
  //loop through values
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var vals = values[i]
    $("#fruits option[value='" + vals + "']").show() //show that option

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row last">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="">Department</label>
    <select id="Type" name="Type" class='form-control'>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
      <option value='Fresh Grape'>Diet 1</option>
      <option value='Blue Apple,Green Apple'>Diet 2</option>
    </select>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="">Device</label>
    <select id="fruits" name="fruits" class='form-control'>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
 
    </select>
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Great, But my list ```var data``` is in views.py, Please guide me how to import that list inside <script> in html?

Comment: im not familiar with django or Python code but i would guess you would create a html template that had the array inside a script tag and use the views.py to render that , but as its not a languare I have ever used you may want to post another question on SO with the tag Python sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get resolve the issue :)

Comment: ah ok glad you were able to work it out